# javascript innerhtml is not responding

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capitalize everything i type inside the text-input the caps function on js works fine which i can see on console but the innerhtml function is not changing the html file

```js
function clr() {
  document.getElementById("box").value = '';
}

function caps() {
  var str = document.getElementById("box").value;
  console.log(str);
  var res = str.toUpperCase();
  console.log(res);
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div id="magic">
      <input id="box">
      <p id="pp">
        <button onclick="clr()">Clear It</button>
        <button onclick="caps()">Capitalize</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

here i can see caps function is working fine on console but not working in HTML file

Comment: inputs use value, not innerHTML

Comment: `box` is an input, it has a `value` not an `innerHTML`

Comment: It solves my problem thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`input` elements don't have an `.innerHTML` property. They have a `.value` property.**

Only elements that have an opening and closing tag can contain any HTML within them, so only elements like: `<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>`, etc. can utilize `.innerHTML`.

You accessed the `value` properly in your `clr` function.

```js
function clr() {
  document.getElementById("box").value = '';
}

function caps() {
  var str = document.getElementById("box").value;
  console.log(str);
  var res = str.toUpperCase();
  console.log(res);
  document.getElementById("box").value = res;
}
```

```html
    <div id="magic">
      <input id="box">
      <p id="pp">
        <button onclick="clr()">Clear It</button>
        <button onclick="caps()">Capitalize</button>
      </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `<input type="text">`there is no innerHTML, they have the `value` attribute for that (you actually used it in the `caps` function).
This should work:

```js
function clr() {
  document.getElementById("box").value = '';
}

function caps() {
  var str = document.getElementById("box").value;
  console.log(str);
  var res = str.toUpperCase();
  console.log(res);
  document.getElementById("box").value = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div id="magic">
      <input id="box">
      <p id="pp">
        <button onclick="clr()">Clear It</button>
        <button onclick="caps()">Capitalize</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```